# Seaborn bar plot y axis has different values than expected

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

The y values in the Seaborn barplot are different than what my data shows.

My data shows:

```
yearmonth
2018-10     763308.0
2018-11     708366.0
2018-12     703952.0
2019-01     844039.0
2019-02     749583.0
2019-03     826114.0
2019-04     951304.0
2019-05    1042708.0
2019-06    1043556.0
2019-07    1201030.0
2019-08    1065393.0
2019-09     881391.0
Freq: M, Name: csp_workload, dtype: float64
```

The plot code is:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(15,5))
sns.barplot(x="yearmonth", y="workload", data = df_all, ci=0)
plt.tight_layout()
```

The output shows values less than the data.  For example, the values for 2018-10 display about 1,800 in the bar plot, but it should be around 763308. Is there something I can do to correct this?

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and it worked for me. 
The only thing I've made was to make sure that yearmonth is being read properly as date format:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['yearmonth'], format='%Y-%m')
```

[image]

You will notice that the yearmonth column changes to

```
  0    2018-10-01
  1    2018-11-01
  2    2018-12-01
```