# Seaborn barchart y values not summed as expected

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

Why are the y-values in my Seaborn barplot not summing correctly? The table below has the expected values, and you can see in the plot below that they do not match. Code is at the end. This is not a duplicate of [Seaborn bar plot y axis has different values than expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58472782/seaborn-bar-plot-y-axis-has-different-values-than-expected) because the issue there was related to datetime formatting.

```
df.groupby(['Category', 'Sub-Category'])['Profit'].sum()

Category    Sub-Category
Furniture   Bookcases        42.4
            Tables          301.3
Supplies    Labels          285.5
            Paper            82.7
Technology  Copiers         -42.1
            Phones          155.0

g = sns.FacetGrid(data=df, col='Category', sharex=False, sharey=False)
g.map_dataframe(sns.barplot, x='Sub-Category', y='Profit', ci=None)
```

[image]

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

### Create dummy data
cat = [ 'Furniture','Supplies','Furniture',
        'Supplies','Furniture','Technology',
        'Technology','Technology','Supplies',
        'Furniture','Supplies','Furniture',
        'Supplies','Furniture', 'Technology',
        'Technology','Technology','Supplies',
]

scat = ['Bookcases','Labels','Tables',
        'Labels','Bookcases','Copiers',
        'Copiers','Phones','Labels',
        'Bookcases','Paper','Tables',
        'Paper','Tables', 'Phones',
        'Phones','Copiers','Paper',
]

prof = [41.1,219.5,6.8,
        -383,2.5, 12.1,
        -71.2,16,449,
        -1.2,9,313,
        92,-18.5,132,
        7,17,-18.3,
]

df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(cat, scat, prof)), 
                    columns =['Category', 'Sub-Category', 'Profit']
                    )

print(df.groupby(['Category', 'Sub-Category'])['Profit'].sum())
g = sns.FacetGrid(data=df, col='Category', sharex=False, sharey=False)
g.map_dataframe(sns.barplot, x='Sub-Category', y='Profit', ci=None)
plt.show()
```

Aside: I also tried catplot, but I couldn't get the empty categories to turn off. For example, "Paper" was still showing up on the x-axis in the "Furniture" category. I used `g = sns.catplot(data=df, x='Sub-Category', y='Profit', col='Category', kind='bar', ci=None,)` and tried adding `sharex=False` or `facet_kws={"dropna": True}`, but that did not work. And it still showed the same y-axis values as the above example.

Comment: Why are you expecting them to be summed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sns.barplot` doesn't make sums.  It just shows bars for its input values.  If multiple bars would end up on the same spot, the average is taken and a confidence interval is shown.

To show the sums, a dataframe with the sums needs to be provided. The `groupby` result can't be used directly, as seaborn expects its data in explicit columns. `.reset_index()` converts the indices into real columns.

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

cat = ['Furniture', 'Supplies', 'Furniture', 'Supplies', 'Furniture', 'Technology', 'Technology', 'Technology',
       'Supplies', 'Furniture', 'Supplies', 'Furniture', 'Supplies', 'Furniture', 'Technology', 'Technology',
       'Technology', 'Supplies', ]
scat = ['Bookcases', 'Labels', 'Tables', 'Labels', 'Bookcases', 'Copiers', 'Copiers', 'Phones', 'Labels', 'Bookcases',
        'Paper', 'Tables', 'Paper', 'Tables', 'Phones', 'Phones', 'Copiers', 'Paper']
prof = [41.1, 219.5, 6.8, -383, 2.5, 12.1, -71.2, 16, 449, -1.2, 9, 313, 92, -18.5, 132, 7, 17, -18.3, ]
df = pd.DataFrame({'Category': cat, 'Sub-Category': scat, 'Profit': prof})

df_summed = df.groupby(['Category', 'Sub-Category'])['Profit'].sum().reset_index()
g = sns.FacetGrid(data=df_summed, col='Category', sharex=False, sharey=False)
g.map_dataframe(sns.barplot, x='Sub-Category', y='Profit')
g.map(plt.axhline, y=0, color='black') # horizontal line at y=0
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: summed bar plot]

To create the plot with `catplot`, also `sharex` needs to be set to `False`. (Note that you need to set an explicit color, because `catplot` default colors the bars via their x-position, which is different for each supblot in the case of `sharex=False`.)

As mentioned in the comments, `barplot` has a parameter `estimator` which can be set to `sum`, and needs `ci` to be turned off. Here is an example:

```py
g = sns.catplot(kind='bar', data=df, x='Sub-Category', y='Profit', estimator=sum, ci=None,
                col='Category', sharex=False, color='dodgerblue')
g.map(plt.axhline, y=0, color='navy')
g.despine(bottom='True')
for ax in g.axes.flat:
    ax.tick_params(axis='both', length=0)
    ax.grid(axis='y', color='grey', ls=':', zorder=0)
```

[image: catplot with estimator=sum]

Comment: I think it's possible to get the desired result with the original dataframe if you do `estimator=sum`, but I'm curious why the OP had the impression that was the default behavior.

Comment: I tried something like that, but the confidence intervals got really long. This confused me. Do they have a statistical meaning when summing? (Turning them off by default would probably also be confusing.)

Comment: It's not surprising the CIs for the sum got large here as the dataset is small and has high variance. I think in general CIs on a sum of random observations can be statistically valid, though in many practical cases they don't really make sense.